Point of Transition from Endothermic to Exothermic Process
Here's a Thermodynamics Problem I recently encountered:
One mole of mono atomic gas is taken from point A to point B through a straight line path as shown in the P-V diagram.find the temperature and volume of the gas at which heat will change its sign i.e. the process becomes exothermic from endothermic. Also calculate the heat supplied to the gas.
I am attaching the solution development below.


The Person who provided the solution assumed a point on the straight line process to be a part of some adiabatic curve since for a Process to transit from Endothermic (dQ>0) to Exothermic (dQ<0) it must pass through a point where dQ=0.
What I don't understand is aren't there infinitely many adiabatic curves passing through the straight line. If so what does it imply physically. What does the intersection of processes on a PV Curve signify??
Thank You!!

Is this a textbook solution?

Not quite, I found it in some YouTube video

https://youtu.be/RJJ5cojnTxg?si=LWH2gDWmkNXJkuCU

The are asking for the volume at which dW/dV goes to zero.

For any positive real $a>0$ there is a single adiabatic process such as $pV^{\gamma}=a$. These curves cover the $p>0, V>0$ quadrant and do not ever cross. Consequently, for any straight line, here one represented by $\overline{AB},$ there is a unique adiabatic curve, say $pV^{\gamma}=a_1$ that is tangential to that segment at some point, here denoted by $C \in \overline{AB}.$
Since the line and the adiabatic curve at $C$ are tangential and both processes are reversible, ie., each point on either represents an equilibrium state, they are infinitesimally identical and therefore at point $C$ an equal amount of entropy enters and leaves the system, that is $dS|_C=0$. In other words $C$ is the point where the process $\overline{AB}$ from endothermic to exothermic and vice versa.
The line $\overline{AB}$ itself will cross an infinity of $pV^{\gamma}=a$ adiabatic curves but will be tangential to only one, the rest will be crossed twice or none at all. This follows from the monotonicity of these adiabatic curves themselves. That the adiabatic curves, or surfaces in the general case where more than two state variables describe a system, cover the quadrant smoothly and contiguously is one of the mathematical ways of proving the existence of the entropy function and absolute temperature.
